# How to get the Handle of a specific explorer window in powershell

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, powershell

I'm following this tutorial here:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/12/26/weekend-scripter-manage-window-placement-by-using-pinvoke/

They use the code

```
(Get-Process -Name PowerShell).MainWindowHandle
```

to get the handle of the process called "PowerShell"

How would I get the handle of a file explorer window with the name "FOO" ?

Comment: `(Get-Process -Name *FOO).MainWindowHandle`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$processId = (Get-Process | ? ProcessName -eq explorer | ? MainWindowTitle -match "pattern")
```

Answer (score 0):

MainWindowHandle doesn't work for explorer.exe. Code below works for me

```
    (New-Object -ComObject 'Shell.Application').Windows() | ForEach-Object { 
        if ($_.locationName -contains "foo") {
             $pwnd = $_.HWND
        }
    }
```